# Remove image overlay layer in Leaflet

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

I'm trying to place a sketch on a building on the map with Leaflet. I succeeded in this as well, I can place and scale an image in svg format on the map. But when I add a new sketch to the map, I want the old sketch to be deleted from the map.

```
    map.removeLayer(sketchLayer)
    sketchLayer.removeFrom(map)
    map.removeLayer(L.sketchLayer)
```

i tried these

My codes,

```
 splitCoordinate (value) {
      const topLeftCoordinates = value.top_left.split(',')
      const topRightCoordinates = value.top_right.split(',')
      const bottomLeftCoordinates = value.bottom_left.split(',')
      this.initMap(topLeftCoordinates, topRightCoordinates, bottomLeftCoordinates)
    },
    initMap (topLeftCoordinates, topRightCoordinates, bottomLeftCoordinates) {
      let map = this.$refs.map.mapObject
      map.flyTo(new L.LatLng(topLeftCoordinates[0], topLeftCoordinates[1]), 20, { animation: true })
      const vm = this
      var topleft = L.latLng(topLeftCoordinates[0], topLeftCoordinates[1])
      var topright = L.latLng(topRightCoordinates[0], topRightCoordinates[1])
      var bottomleft = L.latLng(bottomLeftCoordinates[0], bottomLeftCoordinates[1])
      var sketchLayer = L.imageOverlay.rotated(vm.imgUrl, topleft, topright, bottomleft, {
        opacity: 1,
        interactive: true
      })
      map.addLayer(sketchLayer)
    }
```

Comment: Nice having found the solution yourself! Please consider posting it as an _answer_ below and _accepting_ it, so that people know your issue is fixed, instead of just editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix:
The error was related to the javascript scope. I defined the sketchLayer in the data and my problem solved.